# Is it possible to (uniquely) reverse modulo operation by solving multiple equations with the same original integer?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've tried searching but I haven't been able to find an answer. There are similar questions about reversing modulo operation here on stackexchange, but I haven't found a question which is applicable to my problem.

All answers I've found on reversing modulo says that you cannot uniquely determine the original answer. (At least if I understand them right.)

But let's say we know that:

$x \!\mod 10 = 13\ $ **and** $\ x \!\mod 13 = 2$.

Can we with this method uniquely determine $x$ if we have $n$ amount of these equations? I'm guessing that if $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can do it, but would this be the only case?

I hope I'm making sense, thanks!

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: Well, wouldn't we only be able to determine a solution to modulo $\prod_n m$?

Comment: If you add the product of all modulos to $x$, then that is another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the $n$ equations:
$$
x\bmod m_1=m_2
$$
You won't be able to determine $x$ better than 
$$
\text{lcm}(m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n)
$$
($\text{lcm}$ meaning "least common multiple").

Search for "Chinese remainder theorem" for more information.